# Meaning of ‘in’ in: They had a very fast car to get away in?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

What is the meaning of ‘in’ in the sentence:

> They had a very fast car to get away **in**.

I think if there was not ‘in’, the sentence is right too:

> They had a very fast car to get away.

So, why ‘in’ be added at the end of the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You travel *in* a car - you get inside it.

The sentence:

> They had a very fast car to get away in.

... means the same as:

> They had a very fast car *in which to get away*.

It is quite common for the [preposition to appear at the end of the sentence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/prepositions-ending-a-sentence-with) in this way, for example:

> - He had a spoon with which to eat.
> - He had a spoon to eat with.

If either of these example phrases were missing the ending preposition it would sound like they had to get the car somewhere, rather than get away themselves, or that they were actually eating the spoon rather than eating *with it*.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple statement, the sentence might be written something like:

> They got away **in** a car.

In this case the preposition "in" is the standard used with cars and similar vehicles, as compared with

> They got away **on** a train.

Switching around the word order, as in your examples, puts the preposition at the end where it's somewhat redundant.  It doesn't matter if you say

> The car they used to **get away**

or

> The car they used to **get away in**

as both mean the same thing.  Note that it's an adverb phrase that modifies "used".  If instead you wrote:

> The car they **got away in**

the "in" is required, as it describes *how* they got away.  Otherwise

> The car they **got away**

makes no sense. At best, it implies the car is what "got away", e.g.

> The car that got away

rather than

> The [getaway](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/getaway) car.